# How can I make the radar design look more creative with C# form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I want to simulate a radar in C #. I managed to simulate, but how can I make the look more impressive? I would be glad if you could help.

[The image I want to improve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVm8b.jpg)

You can review the piece of code I have tried below. I couldn't go too far while designing. This is where I want help.I am trying to make a more useful interface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Radar
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer t = new Timer();

    int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 300, HAND = 150;
    int u;
    int cx, cy;
    int x, y;
    int tx, ty, lim = 20;

    Bitmap bmp;
    Pen p;
    Graphics g;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1);
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        cx = WIDTH / 2;
        cy = HEIGHT / 2;
        u = 0;
        t.Interval = 5;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);
        t.Start();

    }

    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p = new Pen(Color.Green, 1f);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        int tu = (u - lim) % 360;

        if (u>= 0 && u <= 180)
        {
            x = cx + (int)(HAND * Math.Sin(Math.PI * u / 180));
            y = cy - (int)(HAND * Math.Cos(Math.PI * u / 180));

        }
        else
        {
            x = cx - (int)(HAND * -Math.Sin(Math.PI * u / 180));
            y = cy - (int)(HAND * Math.Cos(Math.PI * u / 180));
        }

        if (tu >= 0 && tu <= 180)
        {
            tx = cx + (int)(HAND * Math.Sin(Math.PI * tu / 180));
            ty = cy - (int)(HAND * Math.Cos(Math.PI * tu / 180));

        }
        else
        {
            tx = cx - (int)(HAND * -Math.Sin(Math.PI * tu / 180));
            ty = cy - (int)(HAND * Math.Cos(Math.PI * tu / 180));
        }

        g.DrawEllipse(p, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, 80, 80, WIDTH - 160, HEIGHT - 160);

        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(cx, 0), new Point(cx, HEIGHT));
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, cy), new Point(WIDTH, cy));

        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1f), new Point(cx, cy), new Point(tx, 
        ty));
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(cx, cy), new Point(x, y));

        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        p.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();

        u++;
        if (u == 360)
        {
            u = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn´t show how this relates to programming.

Comment: Can you provide what you´ve tried? In particular some code would be meainigful and what you consider to be "more impressive".

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention. I rearranged the post.

Comment: It´s still not clear what you mean by "more useful". Useful to whom? You should focus on your user-group, which we don´t know.

Comment: I mean useful, how can I get a more beautiful and innovative look.  I'm currently getting a very basic output on the interface.

Comment: I do not expect a correct answer. As I stated in the question, I asked for a suggestion.

Comment: But that doesn´t fit SO's format, which **does** rely on right or whrong answers, even though you state you don´t need that.

Comment: you may be right. I notice after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replicate the look of an old analogue radar there are a few effects to consider:

**Blurring**

Analogue scopes are never sharp. So some amount of blurring might be required. One way to get this would be to use anti-aliasing, and upscaling the image. Another would be to use WPF and use the [blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018331/blur-effect-on-image-as-a-window-background)

**Persistence**

Old scopes used very slow phosphors so that radar returns persisted for some time, but with reduced intensity the older the return is. One way to do this would to create a mask where the opacity is proportional to the angle around the center of the image. Draw this mask over the image with a suitable blending mode to reduce the intensity of old radar returns, and rotate the image each frame.

**Noise**

Analogue radars will show all kinds of radar returns. Birds, raindrops, trees, whatever is in the field of view of the radar and produces a return. This causes noise in the image. A simple way to do this would be to create a smaller image that is filled with random data for each pixel. Then draw this on top of your image with a suitable blending mode and opacity.

These effects will be rather difficult to do with just winforms. You will probably need to either do quite a bit of image processing by hand. Or possibly with WPF since this allows for more kinds of effects.